# Rectangular to polar conversion angle error

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to determine the polar form of the following rectangular vector:

```
-105 + 140j
```

The polar form is $\sqrt(-105)^2+140^2$ = 175 and the angle is determined by $\arctan(\frac{140}{-105}) = -53.13$

The answer provided gives an angle of $\theta=126.87$, which is 180 degrees later. Also [this](http://www.intmath.com/complex-numbers/convert-polar-rectangular-interactive.php) website gives the 126.87 degrees.

Why is that and which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visualization:

[image] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceVZt.png))

So $-53.13$ is not a correct answer, it would run clockwise, assigning a point in the $4$-th quadrant.

It is a problem with how to pick $\tan^{-1}$.

[image: tan and choices for an inverse function] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH1wB.png))

The $\color{green}{\text{dark green curve}}$ is the graph of $y = \tan(x)$. If one inverts it, by mirroring it along $y = x$, you would get a multivalued relation, but a function must have at most one value per argument.

So one limits the inverse to a strip parallel to the $x$-axis of width $\pi$.

The $\color{red}{\text{red curve}}$ is the graph of the $\arctan$ function your calculator offered, and is offered by much of the available mathematical software.

The $\color{purple}{\text{purple curve}}$ is the graph of the inverse function you would need, which is $y = \arctan(x) + \pi$

Note that there is nothing wrong with your calculator, instead of offering many versions of $\tan^{-1}$ the user is expected to do the shift himself.

Comment: Yes, but how is it possible I get -53.13 degrees from the calculation? Is my calculation of the angle correct?

Comment: Thanks for you edit. I think it's clear, but I wonder why my calculator uses the "wrong" arctan.

Comment: The calculator had to make a choice and it give angle between -90 and +90 degrees.  The value of the real part of the number tell you if the calculator gave the right angle or if you have to add 180 degrees.

Comment: In your case, the real part is -105, since it is negative you have to add 180 degrees.  $-53.13 + 180=126.87$